# Will JAX-RS support validation groups?

Tags: jax-rs, bean-validation

From JSR-339:

> For simplicity, JAX-RS implementations are NOT REQUIRED to support processing groups other than Default.

This severely limits usefulness of validation in JAX-RS because for example for create and update you are usually using the same model object, but for create the ID of the object should not be provided and for update the ID should be provided, which could be easily validated using validation groups. In general all model objects that are used in more than one flow are impossible to validate.

I do not understand the simplicity argument because Bean Validation already supports groups, so the JAX-RS implementation just needs to pass a group to  Bean Validation implementation like Hibernate Validator.

So are there any plans to add validation groups to JAX-RS?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It turns out that it does support validation groups. From the same JSR-339:

> The presence of @Valid will trigger validation of all the constraint annotations decorating a Java bean class. This validation will take       place in the Default processing group unless the **@ConvertGroup** annotation is present.

For example this is how to validate Account bean in my custom `Create` or `Update` groups rather than the `Default` group:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
Response createAccount(@Valid @ConvertGroup(from = Default.class, to = Create.class)
    Account account)

@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
Response updateAccount(@Valid @ConvertGroup(from = Default.class, to = Update.class)
    Account account)

public class Account {

    @Null(groups = Create.class)
    @NotNull(groups = Update.class)
    private String Id;

}

public interface Create {}

public interface Update {}
```

Comment: Brilliant! I've been looking for this for long time. Though I believe from/to arguments are swapped in the example.

Comment: Keep in mind that the validations that will use the `@Default` group will be not considered anymore, if will use `@ConvertGroup`

Comment: As solution that could not have side effects would be that your new group to extend the `Default` one. In such way will still work the `Default` validations.

Comment: Extend as in `public class Update extends Default`?

Comment: `from = Default.class` is the default and can be omitted